# Access Arabic-named files through FTP

Tags: ftp, arabic

I have a website hosted on GoDaddy windows servers. I want to move the website to another server. I tried to download the whole website files via FTP but there are some files which named in Arabic and when my FTP client (FireFTP) tries to save them on my pc, the file name becomes underscores (e.g. _______.jpg). I cannot change the file names because they are linked from the database (the website is a DotNetNuke CMS).

I am wondering if this problem is due to the FTP server itself or the FTP client I'm using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally could solve this by writing a script (in ASP.NET/C#) to rename all files to numbers (e.g. 1.jpg, 2.doc ....) and then download the renamed files though FTP. The script also genrates commands to rename the files back to the original names in Arabic.